# Hide marker in google map at zoom level 3

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How to hide marker in a google map in zoom level 3, and while zooming in (for upto 16th level) I have to show the marker again. I am using Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Note: There is only one marker in the map.

Can any one help me to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add an `zoom_changed` event to the map, and check which zoomlevel your map is and act accordingly. See also the API Reference: [Map Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) and [Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#OverlaysOverview).

Partial code (you might want to update / add something here and there):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();

    // Update May 2017
    //   You can now use setVisible() on a marker instead of
    //   setting the map to a null value.
    if (zoom <= 3) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    } else {
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I will check and let you know the results.

Comment: Note, the code might not be a 100% working, but that is the main idea what you have to do :). (I just wrote the code based on the API Reference (and my own experience with Google Maps API), I didn't run it.)

Comment: Why you setting map when you can just use setVisible marker method?

Comment: @MrJedi : probably because it didn't exist back in the day (4 years ago). I don't know anymore, it is quite a long time ago.

Comment: @Styxxy I didn't notice how old the answer is :) Please consider, change your answer. Funny fact: my teammate just copied yours code and I wondered why he sets map to null :D Now I know ;p

Comment: @MrJedi I updated the answer, I added is as a comment (I can't look up the exact API at the moment and test the code).